# Override style attribute pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to develop a backwards compatible material app and I ran into a problem. The default selectableItemBackground is all over the place, but it looks good on lollipop (the ripple thing). I wanted to override it only on older versions.

My styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Platform.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/press_overlay_light</item>
</style>
```

and styles.xml (21):

```
<style name="AppTheme.Platform.Light.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

I figured that this will only override it on older versions, but it uses the same background everywhere. I'm building against v21, testing on a v17 emulator and v22 Nexus 5.

I'm not using these themes directly, they're used as a base for more specific themes. I tried copying all of my themes to styles.xml (21), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave this as a monument for my stupidity. The folder for the lollipop themes was called values-21 instead of values-v21. values-21 doesn't really mean anything.